# Emit an event manually in RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-cocoa, rx-swift

I'm a newbie in RxSwift and need a very basic help.
Assump that I have an Observable and subscribe it like this.

```
 let source: Observable<Void> = Observable.create { [weak self] observer in

        guard let _ = self else {
            observer.on(.Completed)
            return NopDisposable.instance
        }

        observer.on(.Next())

        return AnonymousDisposable {

        }
    }
```

And the subscribe like this:

```
 source.subscribeNext { () -> Void in

    }
```

The question is: how can I emit the event to subscribeNext manually every time I need. This is like `rx_tap` behavior on `UIButton`.
I see in the example code has something like this `source = button.rx_tap.asObservale()`. After that, every time user tap to button, there will emit an event and trigger on subscribeNext(). I also want to have that behavior but in programmatically, not from UI event.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Most of the time, you can compose your observable and the solution I'm about to give is not the recommended way to do Rx code.

You can look at [Subject](http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html) to implement the behavior you request. There are multiple variations on subject, that the documentation explains well.

An example usage, inspired from RxSwift's [playground](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/Rx.playground/Pages/Subjects.xcplaygroundpage/Contents.swift):

```
let subject = PublishSubject<String>()

_ = subject.subscribeNext { content in
    print(content)
}
subject.on(.Next("a"))
subject.on(.Next("b"))
```

This will print `"a"` then `"b"`.

For more detail about when to use subject or not, I'd recommend reading [this article](http://davesexton.com/blog/post/To-Use-Subject-Or-Not-To-Use-Subject.aspx).

Comment: Hi @tomahh,
Your solution works. However, what is reason you mentioned it as 'not the recommended way'?
And how about when compare it with ```AnyObserver<Void>```.<br/>
With ```AnyObserver<>```, we can use it like:<br/>
    `var beginLoad: AnyObserver<Void>?`
     `beginLoad = AnyObserver<Void>(eventHandler: { (event) -> Void in
            print("1234543")
        })`
    `beginLoad.on(.Next())`

Comment: Also that ```PublishSubject<String>()``` is not a ```Observable```, so we can't using operators on it (flatten, concat....).

Comment: You can call `asObservable()` on the subject to get it as an `Observable`.

Comment: Subjects are most often used to wrap imperative APIs. You'd usually compose upon already existing observables (rx_tap being a good example). I'd recommend reading [this article](http://davesexton.com/blog/post/To-Use-Subject-Or-Not-To-Use-Subject.aspx), though not in swift, that goes a long way into explaining when to use Subject.

Comment: Yes, I see the way how to subject emit an event. Thanks a lot @tomahh.
The remaining is learn to choose correct type of subject to use :).

Comment: Just to simplify, you can call the method like this: `subject.onNext("b")`

Answer (score 1):

For a Driver, you can do

```
var isSearching: Driver<Bool>

isSearching = Driver.just(true)
```